# How to change old data of table with before insert trigger in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

if new row is inserted into table, if duplicate rows already present i want to merge the two rows into  one

> *table* **TEST** ( *ID column defined as primary key*)
>
> ```
> ID     ITEM     QUANTITY
> --     ----     --------
> 1       KA1        5
> 2       KA2        2
> ```

if new row is inserted to table **test** with values (KA1,6), because item **KA1** already present  new row should be inserted with total quantity 11 and old row should be deleted .

Result set should be as the following :

> ```
> ID     ITEM     QUANTITY
> --     ----     --------
> 2       KA2        2
> 3       KA1       11
> ```

*where used trigger and inline procedure are :*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  MERG_DUP
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  FOR VAL IN(SELECT ID,ITEM,QUANTITY, FROM TEST)
  LOOP
  IF VAL.ITEM=:NEW.ITEM THEN
            :NEW.QUANTITY:=:NEW.QUANTITY+VAL.QUANTITY;
           XXI_MULTI_PR_REMOVE(VAL.ID);
        EXIT;
  END IF;
  END LOOP;
end; 
/


CREATE  OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXI_MULTI_PR_REMOVE(ID number)
IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
L_TID NUMBER;
BEGIN
 L_TID:=ID;
  DELETE FROM  TEST WHERE ID=L_TID;
commit;
END;
/
```

Comment: Deleting the existing row and incrementing the  primary key is not a wise option, rather you could simply update `quantity` with a `merge into`.

Comment: im not incrementing the primary key , new row is inserted with that key , im deleting the old row , old row quantity should be added to new row if both item are same

Comment: So, that means  there is a sequence/ trigger for generating primary keys am I right? or identity column?

Comment: sequence is there

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Edit the question and add part of the code that you have tried so far.. Also remember that to change display of sample data set /code, you need not put html tags. Simply use the `{}` symbol on the toolbar to change the display format.

Comment: I don't know much about your database design (other than what you've written here) but I have to think that keeping all of the data and simply creating a view on the table to return the result you want is probably the better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You do not need to use `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`, and do not use `COMMIT` inline inside your procedures.*

*For your case it's nice to* `CREATE TABLE test` *with* `ID` *column defined as*       `number generated always as identity primary key`.

Therefore, the statements in the following order may be used :

```
 SQL> CREATE TABLE test(
                  id       number generated always as identity primary key,
                  item     varchar2(100),
                  quantity int
 );
 /
 SQL> INSERT INTO test(item,quantity) VALUES ('KA1',5);
 SQL> INSERT INTO test(item,quantity) VALUES ('KA2',2);

 SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXI_MULTI_PR_REMOVE( I_ITEM varchar2 ) IS
 BEGIN
  DELETE TEST WHERE ITEM = I_ITEM;
 END;
 /
 SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MERG_DUP
 BEFORE INSERT ON TEST
 FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE  
      v_qty NUMBER;
 BEGIN
    BEGIN
      SELECT SUM(NVL(QUANTITY,0)) INTO v_qty FROM TEST WHERE ITEM = :NEW.ITEM;
     EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN v_qty := NULL; 
    END;  
    IF ( v_qty IS NOT NULL ) THEN
        XXI_MULTI_PR_REMOVE(:NEW.ITEM);
       :NEW.QUANTITY:=:NEW.QUANTITY+v_qty;    
    END IF;
 END MERG_DUP;
 /
 SQL> INSERT INTO test(item,quantity) VALUES ('KA3',6);
 SQL> COMMIT;
 SQL> SELECT * FROM test;
```